# When a reflexive sheaf is flat over its base

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a projective and smooth variety with a codimension 2 closed subvariety $Z$. Let $Y=X\times \mathbb{A}^2$ and $E$ a reflexive sheaf on $Y$ that is a vector bundle outside of $Z\times \mathbb{A}^1\times \{0\}$.

As shown below every reflexive sheaf on $Y$ is flat over $\mathbb{A}^2$.

Q1) When is the restriction of $E$ to the closed subvarieties of the form $X\times l$ where $l$ is a line in $\mathbb{A}^2$ is a reflexive sheaf? (Other than the obvious case that $l$ doesn't intersect $\mathbb{A}^1\times \{0\}$). This will be true if the restriction of $E$ to the fibers over $\mathbb{A}^2$ are reflexive. Is there a condition on the pair $(X,Z)$ such that it will guarantee for every reflexive sheaf like $E$ its restriction to the fiber over $\mathbb{A}^2$ are also reflexive?

Edit: Here is another relevant question Q2) Let $E$ be a reflexive sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^n$ that is a vector bundle outside of a closed point. Here $n$ is very large. Is the restriction of $E$ to a hyperplane section containing the closed point reflexive?

Edit: Every reflexive sheaf on $X\times \mathbb{A}^2$ is flat over $\mathbb{A}^2$. To show this we need to check it on affine covers and the problem boils down to the following: We have a reflexive $A[x,y]$-module $M$ is its pushforward to $\text{Spec}(k[x,y])$ flat? For reflexive module $M$ we can write it as the kernel in an exact sequence $0\rightarrow M \rightarrow A[x,y]^{\oplus n}\rightarrow N$ where $N$ is torsion free. Pushforward is left exact and gives us the following exact sequence, note pushforward of $A[x,y]^{\oplus n}$ will be a free $k[x,y]$-module of infinite rank:
$$0\rightarrow p_*M \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} k[x,y]\rightarrow p_*N$$ The pushforward of $N$ is torsion-free. If we restrict to the first $n$ components of $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty}k[x,y]$, we get a an exact sequence where the cokernel is torsion-free, this implies the kernel is a reflexive $k[x,y]$-module. Reflexive $k[x,y]$-modules are automatically free modules. This means that $p_*M$ has a filtration of nested sub-modules that are free modules and $p_*M$ is the union of these free modules. I'm not sure whether this implies $p_*M$ is free or not but it implies that it is flat.